# What does the variable stores when it is assigned a printf statement in C

Tags: c, printf

```
       void main(){
       int i;
       i=printf("how r u?\n");
       i=printf("%d",i);
       printf("%d",i);}
```

The above code gives the result as:
how r u?
91
My question:
How does stores 9 and 1??

Comment: "On success, the total number of characters written is returned." : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/  ... an easy search away (yess , that's the C++ reference but it hasn't changed...)

Comment: More related stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3747501/2509

Comment: Just because a question can be answered by reference to a man page doesn't make it a bad question. I'm not sure why this got down-voted. It's a clear and unambiguous question (with easily-enough fixed grammar) with a definite answer.

Comment: @Novelocrat There is a lot of feeling that a question--like this one--that *should* be answered by reading the docs *is* a bad question. The old mantra of *no question too simple* has been overturned.

Comment: Is there a good meta.so link for that sentiment? It seems like something that's not trivially searchable, and generated a much more targeted explanation than one would find in the manual pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf): *Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed.... If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned.*

So you are getting `9` and `i` because `printf` wrote out `9` and `1` characters respectively.

This is also relevant: [Why does printf return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535557/why-does-printf-return-a-value)

Comment: Thank you @cegfault.Me too changed the characters and observed the change

Comment: But this prints -1 and 2.If number of characters will be returned how does 2 come in the second printf statement
`int i=-1;
i=printf("%d",i);
printf("%d",i);`

Comment: @sabarish: "-1" is two characters ("-" and "1")